# Creating Population Sets Using RMSE

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics, population, matching

**See below for edit**

I am using R to create similar population sets and have found the MatchIt package very useful. That said, I recently had a conversation with a colleague about methods in creating population sets. My colleague has argued that it is possible to fit a hypothetical population set by simply taking a sample of the population with the lowest RMSE and using this.

A little on the data set. We are looking at spend trends and have a group of 84 people that we are trying to find a similar population for. The rest of the population set is around 13,000 people, so there isn't a shortage of potential candidates. When making a population set using the MatchIt function in R it uses things like total spend, monthly spend, and change in spend. Then it basically runs a logistic regression to find a segment of the population that most fits these characteristics. Usually I use a 1:1 ratio.

My colleague has a different method. They are calculating change in spend over the previous year and then fitting a population of 2000 that has the lowest RMSE to the group of 84. My argument is that when you fit based on change in spend you don't have the impact of dollar amount of spend and since everything is in percentage terms the RMSE will always be low. Also, the fact that you are using 2000 you end up possibility overfitting and getting a good RMSE simply because you used more observations.

I've been searching everywhere for examples of people using RMSE to fit a population set, but haven't found anything. If someone could point out and example to me that would be great!

All of this said, if someone could provide advice it would be appreciated. Is there an argument for using the RMSE to fit a population set, and if so how would you do this correctly?

**Edit**

Sorry for the confusion. I am confused by the methodology being used as well. My question is basically, has anyone heard of using RMSE to subset a population. Personally, I use propensity scoring and it works great.

My colleague is treating the study group of 84 as the known information in a regression scenario (for calculation purposes). They then select a subpopulation of 2,000 from  the broader population of 13,000 that has the lowest RMSE compared to the study group. What are the drawbacks of doing this?

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. You are calculating RMSE for what exactly (it is a measure of model fit, so I can't see how do you use it for comparing subpopulations)?

Comment: I also don't understand this. Are you looking for a matching sample so that a meaningful contrast can be drawn, as in propensity score matching? Do you want to match participants in a study so that the analyses will be more powerful? Are you trying to find latent clusters in a dataset?

Comment: Edited original post to be more clear. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Lower RMSE of what exactly? How do you calculate it? On what data?